# What is the elegant/Pythonic way to keep variables in scope, yet also catch exceptions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been using Python for a few months now, and I love it so far. I also like how there is usually a single, "Pythonic" way to handle common programming problems.

In code I've been writing, as I make calls to network functions and have to handle exceptions, I keep running into this template of sorts that I end up writing:

```
proxyTest = None
try:
    proxyTest = isProxyWorking(proxy)
except TimeoutError:
    break

if proxyTest:
    ...
```

This is my way of declaring proxyTest so that it is in scope when I need to use it, yet also calling the function that will return a value for it inside of the proper exception handling structure. If I declare proxyTest inside of the try block, it will be out of scope for the rest of my program.

I feel like there has to be a more elegant way to handle this, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: The scope inside the try suite is the same as the scope outside it.  I'm not sure what you mean by:  "If I declare proxyTest inside of the try block, it will be out of scope for the rest of my program."  Could you write a minimal example which demonstrates the problem that you have, rather than an example of the solution that you've come up with?

Comment: It won't be out of scope. It'll be in scope, but undefined (raise `UnboundLocalError` on use). But that's just terminology and doesn't affect the question.

Comment: @mgilson If `proxyTest = None` is left out, and `isProxyWorking` raises `TimeoutError`, then `if proxyTest:` will raise an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @delnan -- Or `NameError` if not in a function.  That has nothing to do with *scope* though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of better options, continue your flow control in the `else` block:

```
try:
    proxyTest = isProxyWorking(proxy)
except TimeoutError:
    break
else:
    #proxyTest is guaranteed to be bound here
```

Or handle the failure case in the except block.

```
try:
    proxyTest = isProxyWorking(proxy)
except TimeoutError:
    proxyTest = None
#proxyTest is guaranteed to be bound here
```

Whichever is better depends on context, I think.

Comment: I like this answer. In my case, I was just mistaking something being undefined because of an exception with being out of scope. But these solutions give me some flexibility based on the flow of the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The obvious alternative would be to do the 'false' initialization in the `except` block:

```
try:
    proxyTest = isProxyWorking(proxy)
except TimeoutError:
    proxyTest = None
```

Whether this is easier/more appropriate than your constructions depends on how complicated the logic is in the middle, though.

Comment: This makes sense. I think I was mistaking the fact that, in the case of an exception, proxyTest was simply never declared (causing an error), as opposed to being out of scope. Is that correct?

Comment: Right- as @delnan commented in the question, the end result is that `proxyTest` never gets defined. But anything defined in the try/except is in the same scope as the parent code.

Answer (score -1):

I would put the code after

```
if proxyTest:
```

in the try block, just after binding proxyTest.

Comment: In general, this is in danger of catching too much (i.e. swallowing errors in the rest of the code).

Comment: I wouldn't -- Then you may inadvertantly catch an exception elsewhere that you really shouldn't.

Comment: @delnan -- Jinx.  You owe me a coke.  or something like that ;-)

Comment: but he's catching only TimeoutError, not other kinds of exceptions. Anyway looks like everybody agrees :-) so I'll look into this.

Comment: big try blocks are a code smell ... `try` block should generally just have one line in it, whenever possible